# VB Script Inside HTML

Tags: html, sql, outlook

I have an app which creates html code displaying the results of a DTS Package and then sends it to the user. Within the DTS Package I have an ActiveX script which moves the file into an archive folder, but what I would like is for that code to run when the user clicks on a link sent within that email. In other words, the user gets an email with results; if the user likes the results then clicks on a link and the file then gets moved into the archived folder. Is this at all possible?

All users utilize Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a page on an IIS server that intercepts the URL in the email and can identify the file to be moved using the querystring.

Based on this you can then execute a SQL statement that fires a stored procedure which in-turn executes another DTS package that will move the file.

How you do this will depend on which server-side language you want to use.

I haven't done this type of thing on over 10 years, so the details are a little foggy, but hopefully this gives you a start.

See: [Stored Procedures classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424515/stored-procedures-classic-asp)