# Output params and Stored Procedure

Tags: asp-classic

I've googled but none of the solutions seems to work for me! 
I have a SPROC in SQL Server which has an input param and also an output parameter being set within the SPROC.

using classic ASP, I want to retrieve the value of that output parameter but nothing seems to get set (but I can see the output parameter working correctly when executing in the SQL Server Management Studio)

```
OpenConnection

Set cmdTemp = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmdTemp.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc
Set cmdTemp.ActiveConnection = dbConn
cmdTemp.CommandText =  "GetCerts"   
cmdTemp.Parameters.Refresh
cmdTemp.Parameters(1) = "ABC123"
cmdTemp.Parameters(2).Direction = 2 'Output

Set reader = cmdTemp.Execute

Response.Write(cmdTemp.Parameters(2)) ' Nothing is displayed at all. 

CloseConnection
```

I tried using the named parameters approach but always got an error saying that the parameters are out of range, wrong arguments or wrong type (Something similar to this).

Really... getting a headache. I just want the OUTPUT param value set from the SPROC (2nd parameter in the SPROC)

Answer (score 0):

Check for errors:

```
Set reader = cmdTemp.Execute

If Err.number <> 0 or  dbConn.Errors.Count <> 0 Then
   'Do something to handle the error
End If
```

Do you have permissions to execute the stored procedure? i.e. the credentials of the ASP user...

[Execute Stored Procedure from Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689736/execute-stored-procedure-from-classic-asp)

Comment: Yes, permissions are good. I can confirm without specifying the output param that I get the recordset correctly and can display the data but I DO need that output param. I also did check for the errors like you mentioned and no errors being reported.

Comment: Completely wierd. It only displays the input params but does not get the output parameter value at all, even though the SPROC sets it and I can see it when executing the SPROC in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems after a long long investigation that what I am trying to do is not possible (but it is in .NET). Seems I need to execute the command twice, first time getting the output parameters values then the next time to display the results. Awful. Praise .NET!

Comment: That's a strong argument; you have any proof for that?

Answer (score 0):

Most collections in the COM world use zero-based indexing. Try using `Parameters(0)` as the input parameter and `Parameters(1)` as the output parameter.

Comment: no it doesnt work like that :) Remember, this is VBScript so 0 really isnt the first parameter. But I tried it anyway and it did not work.