# Simple fetch ASP prepared statement

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I've used php for everything, but now I need to look up something in MS SQL with ASP.

I cannot for the love of God figure out how to bind post parameters to a prepared statement and print the results.

I need to fetch only 1 row for each lookup, where the SQL statement would look like:

SELECT ID,NAME FROM MEMBERS WHERE ID = ?

I've gotten as far as this, from an example and reading a bit of posts:

```
Response.Buffer = True
On Error Resume Next
Dim host
Dim port
Dim user
Dim password
Dim database

host = "host"
port = "1433"
user = "user"
password = "pass"
database = "database"

Dim conn
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Dim ds
ds = host & "," & port
Dim connString
connString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & ds & ";Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=" & database & ";User Id=" & user & ";Password=" & password & ";"

conn.Open connString

Dim cmdPrep1 As New ADODB.Command

Set cmdPrep1.ActiveConnection = cn
cmdPrep1.CommandText = "SELECT ID,NAME FROM MEMBERS WHERE ID =?"
cmdPrep1.CommandType = adCmdText
cmdPrep1.Prepared = True
```

This is where my knowledge ends.

How would I bind input paramters (POST) to the above and do a print of the fetched row?

Why are basic ASP examples so hard to come by vs. php? Seems odd to me.

Comment: Seen as though there of numerous examples of parameters in stored procedures using Classic ASP it doesn't look like you've tried very hard.

Comment: Case in point 10 seconds and I've found this [Answer by Alex K to Execute Stored Procedure from Classic ASP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2689825/692942). Here's an idea of a [simple search in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp-classic%5D+stored+procedure) that would have got you some where without posting your own question.

Comment: I can make no sense of that post. It seems they're returning the parameters bound, not anything from a result set.

Comment: Searches in SO gives me a huge amount of posts with 0 answers. If you can solve my problem, please help me do so instead of pointing out that I "could" have figured it out on my own, because, yes, I probably can, using 10x the time it would take for someone who knows ASP to provide me with a proper solution. If you are that someone, please assist me.

Comment: The fact I've answered this question numerous times in different guises is why I won't sorry. Look at `cmdPrep1.Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("parametername", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))` See [Parameters Collection (ADO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms675869(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: So I use that to bind paramters, then:
 .Execute

 Response.Write .Parameters(0).Value to get the row value?

Comment: Yes. Specify your parameters and append them in the order they are defined in the stored procedure with the correct data types and you are good to go.

Comment: Okay. I think I can get somewhere with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will not work in classic asp:

```
Dim cmdPrep1 As New ADODB.Command
```

you have to use server.createobject like so:

```
dim cmdPrep1 : set cmdPrep1 = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

cmdPrep1.ActiveConnection = cn
cmdPrep1.CommandType = adCmdText
cmdPrep1.CommandText = "SELECT ID,NAME FROM MEMBERS WHERE ID =?"


cmdPrep1.parameters.Append cmd.createParameter( "ID", adInteger, , , Request.Form("nameOfIDField") )

dim rs : set rs = cmdPrep1.execute
```

now you have an [ADODB.Recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510(v=vs.85).aspx) in your variable rs.